# Splash weapon area

Tags: pathfinder-1e

The description for splash weapons says:

> A hit deals direct hit damage to the target, and splash damage to all creatures within 5 feet of the target.

Does that mean that it hits a 3x3 area, or a plus sign? Are diagonals included? I know for the purposes of movement, moving diagonally once only counts as five feet.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you include the diagonals, because the diagonals are within five feet.

When calculating distance along diagonals, one uses a “5, 10” alternating scheme: the first diagonal square is within 5 feet (and therefore within the splash), the second diagonal square is 10 feet beyond that (i.e. 15 feet), so it would not be within a 10-ft. splash, e.g. [stink bomb](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/alchemist/discoveries/paizo---alchemist-discoveries/stink-bomb).

The section on [Throwing a Splash Weapon](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Throw-Splash-Weapon) has more details.